# unexpected character 'ï', parsing JSON with Jackson

Tags: java, android, json, wordpress

I'm writing an android application, in which I need to parse only a JSON url. The JSON content of the url is auto-generated by Wordpress. I'm pretty sure I've written the mapping to the Java classes well, if anything I've tested it with an older url that I've used in an older application and it parsed it correctly.in every class I've turned on

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
```

an I'm getting this exception

```
org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('ï' (code 239)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')
```

and that is how I parse the url in order to get it mapped to my Java objects

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

JsonRequestMapping jsonRequest = mapper.readValue(new URL("http://rhodes-infokiosk.gr.148-251-154-143.smartculture-webgis.eu/?cat=270&json=1"), JsonRequestMapping.class);
```

I won't post the mapping classes because it's just the field with getters and setter if you need me to, just let me know.

I'm really stuck here..

Comment: What does the JSON look like? (Enter the URL in the address bar of your browser and look at the output). It's most likely not valid JSON.

Comment: it is...that is why i've included the url in my question. I've parsed it with online json viewer..

Comment: I think that the problem is in the encoding, because on this URL there are many special characters, try to set the encoding to Unicode or something like this

Comment: that's probably not it. I've used wordpress generated json in my other apps as well and it worked fine...

Comment: have you used word pressed generated json with this exact content???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first newline makes the response invalid JSON.

Comment: i didn't noticed this before, I'm checking it now, But how can I parse it online if it's not valid?

Comment: this is valid json, if you access that url and copy and paste the resulting json into an online json validator it shows as valid. the issue will be the content, e.g. these Το συγκρότημα της Καλλιθέας κτίστηκε στην ίδια